# How to change name of Hibernate Tools reverse engineerd DAO class?

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering, freemarker, hibernate-tools

So im trying to use Hibernate Tools to reverse engineer my database and I am just getting into using Freemarker templates to weak the code it generates. The problem is I want to change the name of the DAO classes it generates. By default the DAO classes are named in the form PersonHome however to change the name to PersonDAO i modified the dao/daohome.ftl.

While this did change the generated class name to PersonDAO the java file was still called PersonHome.java.

Is there a place I can also change the generated file name to match the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok well I have got to the bottom of it myself. It seems while hibernate tools does support changing the filename the feature is not exposed in the Hibernate tools plugin for Eclipse which is frustrating. Instead I have had to create an ant build script to run the reverse engineering like follows.

```
<project name="Reverse Engineer" basedir=".">

<path id="toolslib">
 <path location="lib/hibernate3.jar" />
 <path location="lib/hibernate-tools.jar" />
 <path location="lib/freemarker.jar" />
 ...
 <path location="${jdbc.driver.jar}" />
</path>


<taskdef name="hibernatetool" 
         classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask" 
         classpathref="toolslib" />


<hibernatetool destdir="src">
   <jdbcconfiguration 
        configurationfile="src/hibernate.cfg.xml"
        packagename="my.package.name"
        revengfile="hibernate.reveng.xml">
   </jdbcconfiguration>

   <hbmtemplate destdir="src" 
        templatepath="templates"
        template="dao/daohome.ftl"
        filepattern="{package-name}/{class-name}DAO.java">
            <property key="ejb3" value="false" />
            <property key="jdk5" value="true" />
            <property key="sessionFactoryName" value="my.HibernateSessionFactory" />
        </hbmtemplate>

    </hibernatetool>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "Generic Exporter `<hibernatetemplate>`" tool instead of "`DAO Code(.java)`".
Along with it set the following attributes in the

1. `templatename[customtemplate.ftl]` for this we may use the existing `daohome.ftl` which is available in `hibernate-tools.jar`.
2. filePattern as `${package-name}\${class-name}DAO.java`

and required properties like `sessionFactoryName`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look closely at this but I think you'll have to modify the `DAONewExporter` class (see [HBX-343](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HBX-343) for some inspiration).

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the bits that were missing.

Use case:
Modify DAO names class generated by hibernate tools

Solution:
I used mvn with ant to do this.A roundabout way but its easier for those who have mvn set up.

```
<taskdef name="hibernatetool"
            classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>


<target name="gen_hibernate"
            description="generate hibernate classes">
    <hibernatetool destdir="${basedir}/src/main/java">
        <jdbcconfiguration 
    configurationfile="${basedir}/hibernate.cfg.xml"
    packagename="com.bcbsmt.eie.framework.dto"
    revengfile="${basedir}/hibernate.reveng.xml">
        </jdbcconfiguration>

        <hbmtemplate destdir="${basedir}/src/main/java" 
    templatepath="${basedir}/src/main/resources/template"
    template="dao/daohome.ftl"


    filepattern="{package-name}/{class-name}DAO.java">
            <property key="ejb3" value="false" />
            <property key="jdk5" value="true" />

        </hbmtemplate>

        <hbmtemplate destdir="${basedir}/src/main/java" 
                templatepath="${basedir}/src/main/resources/template"
                template="pojo/Pojo.ftl"


                filepattern="{package-name}/{class-name}.java">
                        <property key="ejb3" value="false" />
                        <property key="jdk5" value="true" />

                    </hbmtemplate>


    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```

maven POM:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.bcbsmt
    HibernateAnnnotationSample
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                               <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml">
                                <target name="gen_hibernate" />
                            </ant>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Jars needed:
These jars should be in ${basedir}/lib folder.Versions are as per your wish

asm-1.5.3.jar
cglib-2.1_3.jar
commons-collections-20030418.083655.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.8.jar
hibernate-3.3.2.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar
hibernate-tools-3.2.4.GA.jar
jtidy-r8-20060801.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
sqljdbc-4.0.jar